# Connecting 50 Microphones on a raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3b+, microphone

I want to create a microphone array like in the image below...

How can I do it for a raspberry device ?

I want the input to be stored for a few seconds on the sd card, and not to have a live stream, if live stream is possible, that would even be better....

would I need a multiplexer, if so, how many ones?

[image]

Comment: what would the microphone array accomplish that a single microphone could not?

Comment: what is the form of the data from the microphone array?

Comment: Is that a microphone array or Lego piece?

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> 1. How to connect Rpi to 50 microphones?
> 2. How to store a few seconds of analog audio signal on the SD card?
> 3. Need a multiplexer? if so, how many?

***Short Answer***

> 1. A quick and dirty hobbyist DIY wiring is to connect the 50 microphones to a structured/layered multiplexer/dimultiplexer of
>      analog switches.
> 2. You can use an Analog To Digital (ADC) chip/module to convert the few seconds of analog signals to a long string/array of digital
>      values, and stored it in SD card.
> 3. You can use any analog multiplexor/demultiplexor such as HC4351.

***Long Answer***

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[MCP3008 SPI 8 Channel 10 bit ADC](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21295c.pdf)

[CD74HC4051-EP Analog Multiplexer and Demultiplexer [Supports Defense and Aerospace Applications]  - Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4051-ep.pdf)

[MC74HC4351 Analog Multiplexers/Demultiplexers with Address Latch using High−Performance Silicon−Gate CMOS [Obsolete version, to replace by newer version] - On Semiconductor/Fairchild Semiconductor](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74HC4351-D.PDF)

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Analog Mux/Demux Block Diagram*

[image: analog mux block diagram]

*Appendix B- 8 Channel ADC Block Diagram*

[image: mcp3008 block diagram]

*Appendix C - Mini Microphone and Power Amplifier*

[image: mike and amp]